# What is this function doing in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, promise

I'm learning JavaScript and I'm learning about Promises. I'm having a hard time to understand the following code:

```
const button = document.querySelector("button");
const div = document.querySelector("div");

const setText = (text) => {
  div.textContent = text
}

const checkAuth = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setText('Checking Auth...')
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(true);
    }, 2000);
  });
};

const fetchUser = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setText('Fetching User...');
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({ name: "Max" });
    }, 2000);
  });
};

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  checkAuth()
     .then(
        isAuth => {
          if (isAuth) {
            return fetchUser()
          }
        }
      )
      .then(
        user => {
          setText(user.name)
        }
      )
});
```

I understand the first two functions `checkAuth` and `fetchUser`, they return a resolved `Promise` after 2 seconds.

I can't really understand how does the event listener of `button` work. I see it calls `checkAuth()` and when executed, the div text of the HTML document changes to `Checking Auth...` for two seconds (until the function resolves successfully the `Promise`. When resolved, it enters into the `.then()` part of the code.

I'm struggling to understand where does `isAuth` and `user` come from. I feel like they are some implicit declaration of a function (called inside themselves?), it's looking really odd to me.

Comment: The `isAuth` is returned from the promise and the `user` is returend by `.then`. See my answer below

Comment: The click listener executes a function. This function then runs `checkAuth()` which is asynchronously. So, you'll get a promise back. With `then()` a callback is registered. As soon as the promise returns, the callback is executed. If the user is authenticated, another asynchronous function is returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`checkAuth()` returns a promise and the value with which it resolves is passed to the callback function of `checkAuth().then(...)` which is then assigned to `isAuth` parameter.

In the case of `user`, it is the value with which the promise returned by `checkAuth().then()` is resolved. If the callback function of `checkAuth().then(...)` returns a non-promise value, `user` will be that non-promise value.

If the callback function of `checkAuth().then()` returns a promise, then `user` will be the value with which that promise, returned by the callback function, resolves.

Here's a simplified example that might help you understand how `isAuth` and `user` are assigned a value:

```js
Promise.resolve(true)
.then(isAuth => {
  console.log("isAuth: " + isAuth);
  return { name: "John Doe" };
})
.then(user => console.log(user));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the explanation:

```js
const button = document.querySelector("button");
const div = document.querySelector("div");

const setText = (text) => {
  div.textContent = text
}

const checkAuth = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setText('Checking Auth...')
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(true); // The return value when the promise resolves which is in this case is `true`;
    }, 2000);
  });
};

const fetchUser = () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setText('Fetching User...');
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve({ name: "Max" }); // Here when the promise resolves it is returning `{ name: "Max" }`;
    }, 2000);
  });
};

button.addEventListener("click", () => {
  checkAuth()
     .then(isAuth => { // This is an arrow function, you can see we are accepting the `isAuth` parameter;
          if (isAuth) { // Regular if...
            return fetchUser() // And the this also returns an promise
          }
        }
      )
      .then(user => { // Which is resolved here, And the user is the `{ name: "Max" }`;
          setText(user.name)
        }
      )
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`isAuth` is returned by `checkAuth` and `user` is returned by `fetchUser`.

I'll re-write this in async/await format. You can compare to make better sense of it.

```
const delay = (time) => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res(), time));

const checkAuth = async () => {
  setText('Checking Auth...');
  await delay(2000);
}

const fetchUser = async () => {
  setText('Fetching User...');
  await delay(2000);
}

const executeOrder = async () => {
  const isAuth = await checkAuth();
  if (isAuth) {
    const user = await fetchUser();
    setText(user.name)
  }
}

button.addEventListener("click", executeOrder);
```